# Как добавить таблицу в локальную базу данных?

Tags: access, база-данных, visual-basic

Доброго времени суток всем! Подскажите, кто может. Как программно из VB 2008 добавить таблицу в локальную базу данных  Access или SQL CE 3.5?

Answer (score 1):

Извините, код где-то затерялся, но вот:

- Обращение к базе данных Access с
     помощью пространства имен `OleDb`, вот
     ссылка в [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.oledb.aspx) - по каждому
     параметру найдете пример на VB ;)
- Формат sql запроса можно найти [здесь](http://citforum.ru/programming/32less/les34.shtml)

Пару лет назад работал с Access из Visual Basic 2005. Не думаю, что многое изменилось.

Comment: Вот смотрите, там примеры по `OleDbCommand` и пишите SQL-запросы вида `CREATE TABLE`...

Comment: Спасибо, буду копать, но может кто подскажет по  SQL CE 3.5?
Собственно наброски проэкта написаны с ним.